# Find distribution and statistical independence based on calculations of conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, random-variables, independence

We have two rvs $X$ and $Y$ and calculated
$$Pr\{X > x| Y = y\} = g(x) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
Can we argue that based on \eqref{eq1} $Pr\{X > x\}=g(x)$ and now since $Pr\{X > x| Y = y\} = Pr\{X > x\}$ rvs $X$ and $Y$ are statistically independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if we have $\forall x~\forall y~.\mathsf P(X\,{>}\,x\mid Y\,{=}\,y)=g(x)$, then that is a valid conclusion.

Being a monovariate function of $x$ for all values of $x$ and $y$ clearly indicates that the conditional probability is independent of the realisation of $Y$, and therefore that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.